# Update Dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

Afternoon,

I have a dataset with c2500 observations of which I want to work 200 a day. This original 2500 might change on a daily basis as data might come out or new data go in, so I need to join this updated list each day.

So far, I can create the starting list and I am using a Do While Loop to extract 200 obs which have a variable in called 'Worked' which changes from N to Y.

What I want to do is update the original list instead of creating a new one so I have 1 copy which only pulls 200 unworked obs.  Whats the best way to do this?

Below is what I have so far:-

RETAIN COUNTER;

```
IF SENT = 'N' and COUNTER <= 200 then do;
    IF COUNTER = . then COUNTER = 1;
    COUNTER = COUNTER + 1;
    SENT = 'Y';
    output WORK.TODAYSLIST;
    END;
```

OUTPUT WORK.STORE ;

Comment: I think I have resolved this by combining all the 200 daily files and left joining them to the original list and only selecting the observations which have a null response on the right side (the obs aren't in the daily list)